# Как сделать блок анимации с валиком

Tags: javascript

https://stconstruction.ru/ - на этом сайте идет анимация валика, только в момент скрола.
Как решил реализовать взять статику и гиф и в момент скрола, начинать анимацию, попробовал функцию window.addEventListener - но анимация не останавливается, даже когда не скролишь.

window.addEventListener('scroll', function()  {

```
img.attr('src', 'https://static.tildacdn.info/tild6633-6663-4733-a234-643035333337/platen-last.gif');
```

}

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы проинспектируете код, увидите что в блоке с классом `main-block__img__img` есть 2 картинки. Одна статическая, а другая - гифка с CSS свойством  `opacity: 0`
При скролле у этой гифки добавляется класс is-active, и гифка становится видимой.

Ссылка на статическую картинку:
https://stconstruction.ru/wp-content/themes/st-construction/img/platen-last.png

Ссылка на гифку:
https://stconstruction.ru/wp-content/themes/st-construction/img/platen-last.gif

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Невнимательно прочитал вопрос, и ответил. Но в моём ответе всё равно есть ответ на ваш вопрос. Поверх тега img со статической картинкой есть прозрачный img с гифкой. При скролле прозрачность убирается и вы видите гифку